# Xamarin.Forms some svgs not rendering

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to get SVG's to work in a mobile app. So I am using FFImage renderer to render the svg from xml. I have gotten one SVG to work. However, this does not work with all valid svg's. The only solution I can come up with is that the SVG below that does not render has multiple  tags within a higher up svg tag. Here is the C# and XAML I am using to render

C#:
    uiSVGImage.Source = SvgImageSource.FromSvgString("Insert the xml from the below files here!");

XAML:

This SVG works fine with my code
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqqvzuHMZi8fi2DUDoneQ7u-QfQb

This SVG does not render
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqqvzuHMZi8fi2EGyvvhQrZk2vqK

Comment: <svgIcon:SvgCachedImage x:Name="uiSVGImage" /> This is the XAML. I realized after I posted it I never put it in

Comment: The SVG that does not render has all of its contents commented out.

Comment: @RobertLongson, here is the updated link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqqvzuHMZi8fi2EGyvvhQrZk2vqK